# Why is input pattern attribute not working for numerics?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I can't get [the pattern attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) on a text input to be limited to numbers.  According to [the javascript regular expressions list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), [d] or [0-9] should do it.  But in

```
<input dir="ltr" type="text" title="Enter numbers only." pattern="[\d]{9}" id="uid" name="1" placeholder="Enter UID" required="'required'" class="required placeholder" minlength="9" maxlength="9" autocomplete="off" />
```

it doesn't work for me (in any browsers).  I have to add js validation such as the following (decided to go this route for simplicity based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)):

HTML:

```
onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'
```

js:

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I mainly want to know if there's a way I can get the pattern attribute to work.  But also feel free to comment on whether I'm using best practices route for this.  I don't want to use HTML5 `<input type="number"/>` as it's not widely supported enough yet.

Comment: Have you tried using `[0-9]{9}` instead ?

Comment: what browser and version are you using? the pattern attribute is also html and supported only in the latest browsers (i.e. IE9 doesn't support it).

Comment: Seems to be working fine. I added a CSS check to give red when invalid and green when valid: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHWcu/).

Comment: The validation for the `pattern` attribute will not prevent adding incorrect information, but it will prevent submitting the form. You can also use the CSS selectors @Jerry used in his demo.

Comment: See this update of @Jerry's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bHWcu/1/

Comment: @Ingo Nice fiddle you got there :)

Comment: I didn't see the `minlength="9"` and `maxlength="9"` on the tag. If exactly nine digits is what you want, my answer wasn't relevant.

Comment: @Sniffer, Yes, I have tried `[0-9]{9}` but also with no effect.  @Nicolás Straub Valdivieso Doesn't work for me in latest Chrome, in latest FF, or IE10 or IE9.

Comment: “Does not work” is not a problem description. Please specify what you expected and what happened instead. Note that the `pattern` attribute is not meant to *prevent* entering data that does not correspond to the pattern, just to signal it as invalid.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela sorry for not being more descriptive on that point; and yes, I was expecting it to prevent entering data.  See accepted answer below.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The validation for the `pattern` attribute will not prevent writing incorrect information into the field, but it will prevent submitting the form. The element also has an `oninvalid` event that will be called when the validation fails during the submit.

Alternatively, you can also use the CSS selectors `:valid`  and `:invalid` to provide instant visual feedback.

Fiddle showing both (based on Jerry's fiddle from the comments): http://jsfiddle.net/bHWcu/1/

```
<form onsubmit="alert('Submitted');">
    <input dir="ltr" type="text" title="Enter numbers only." pattern="[\d]{9}" id="uid" name="1" placeholder="Enter UID" required="'required'" class="required placeholder" maxlength="9" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Note that any client-side validation should only be used for fast feedback to improve the user experience. The actual validation should always be done server-side, as the client-side validation can easily be cheated.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you.  That was exactly my confusion: I thought the pattern attribute was supposed to disable the user from entering in invalid characters.  Thanks everyone for the lightning fast feedback.

Comment: +1 Might also add that the square brackets are not required for the pattern :)

Comment: Actually preventing entering data can be a slippery slope anyway, and it can be somewhat annoying, too. For example, `\d{9}` being validated on every keystroke would prevent the user from ever entering anything other than all 9 digits at once (through copy-paste).

Comment: Drop `minlength`, it is pointless and invalid. The markup could also be simplified in a few ways. But the main point is that the code in the answer is basically the same as in the question, so a casual reader will not immediately see what the *problem* was and what the *solution* is.

Comment: You're right on the `minlength` attribute, I removed it. If a casual reader decides not to read literally my first sentence, which clearly states the problem and solution, that is up to them.

Comment: You could also add the min requirement to the pattern like this "\d{9,9}" that way, if you don't have at least 9 characters, it won't be valid either.

Comment: @Leo `{9}` is short-hand for `{9,9}`.

Comment: I thought so.. Any simple attribute to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

The `pattern` attribute only prevents the form from being submitted if its value does not match. To actually prevent the user from entering invalid text, `checkValidity()` can be used.

Demo:

```js
let prevVal = "";
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(e){
  if(this.checkValidity()){
    prevVal = this.value;
  } else {
    this.value = prevVal;
  }
});
```

```html
Only enter digits: <input pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for pointing out checkValidity(). This looks to be super useful.

Answer (score 0):

A revised version to Unmitigated's answer.

```
let prevVal = "";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
//window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    document.querySelector('INPUT').addEventListener('input', function(e){
      if(this.checkValidity()){
        prevVal = this.value;
      } else {
        this.value = prevVal;
      }
    });    
});
```